# Receiving an error when trying to store Oracle Procedure. Procedure works when not stored

Tags: oracle

-- Hi! I've been having trouble storing the ComplexProc in a procedure. I can get it to work when I replace the 'Create or replace' line of code with 'declare', but for the assignment I need to be able to store the code in a variable called ComplexProc. Any ideas?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ComplexProc () IS
    cursor emp is
    SELECT Ssn, Dno, Fname, Minit, Lname, Salary FROM Employee e WHERE e.Ssn = (SELECT Essn FROM Works_on wo
                                                                                                    WHERE Pno NOT IN ( SELECT p.Pnumber FROM Project p INNER JOIN Department d ON p.Dnum = d.Dnumber
                                                                                                                      INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.Dno = d.Dnumber WHERE e.Ssn = wo.Essn)
                                                                                                    AND Essn IN (SELECT Ssn FROM Employee e 
                                                                                                                WHERE e.Salary > ( SELECT Avg(Salary) FROM Employee e2 WHERE e.Dno = e2.DNo )
                                                                                                                AND (SELECT Count(Dependent_name) FROM Dependent d WHERE e.Ssn = d.Essn) >= 2)
                                                                                                    GROUP BY Essn HAVING Sum(Hours) >= 10);
                                                                                    
    emp_rec emp%rowtype;
    emp_NumDependents INT;
    emp_NonDepHours INT;
    emp_DepHours INT;

begin

    open emp;
    fetch emp into emp_rec; -- initial fetch

    emp_NumDependents := 0;
    while emp%found loop        -- still more data to fetch

        SELECT Count(Dependent_name) INTO emp_NumDependents FROM Dependent d WHERE d.Essn = emp_rec.Ssn;

        SELECT Sum(Hours) INTO emp_NonDepHours FROM Works_on wo
        WHERE wo.Pno NOT IN (SELECT p.Pnumber FROM Project p WHERE p.Dnum = emp_rec.Dno)
        AND wo.Essn = emp_rec.Ssn;

        SELECT Sum(Hours) INTO emp_DepHours FROM Works_on wo
        WHERE wo.Pno IN (SELECT p.Pnumber FROM Project p WHERE p.Dnum = emp_rec.Dno)
        AND wo.Essn = emp_rec.Ssn;
      
        dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.Fname||' '||emp_rec.Minit||' '||emp_rec.Lname||' '||emp_rec.Salary||' '||emp_NumDependents||' '||emp_NonDepHours||' '||emp_DepHours);
        fetch emp into emp_rec;
    end loop;  
    close emp;
end;
/

commit;
```

Thanks!

I got the procedure to work by replacing the 'Create or Replace' line with 'declare'. However, I need to store it in ComplexProc for the assignment. I tried Changing the 'Is' to 'As', adding and removing the declare. However, no matter how many times I change the wording I can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi check you declaration line you have the "()" , you only need them when you have any parameters to the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the empty parenthesis:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ComplexProc IS
```